# How can I dynamically adjust the frame size and the display frame region in OpenCV camera capture?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was trying to build a model that can dynamically adjust the display region of the camera capture in OpenCV according to the detections. I found frame and resolution resizing methods, but what if I want to focus on a particular region of the entire capture? How can I do that?

I tried the cv2.resize() method, and the cap.set() method, which changed the frame size and the resolution respectively, but I could not make the feed to get focused on a particular region of the entire captured frame

Answer (score 0):

If I've got your idea correct, you want to crop a part of an image with coordinates based on your detection. OpenCV represents images with arrays, so with exaple image:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/1.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(img)

print(img.shape)
```

[image]

Then you just access array's part by indexing and get its cropped part:

```
plt.imshow(img[250: 450, 250: 450])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how the same can be done with cap.read() ?

Comment: If by cap, you mean `cv2.VideoCapture(), cap.read()`, which returns returns bool and frame arguments, then you can do exactly the same with the frame you've got, since it's still openCVs representation